# How can I integrate WPML or other multilingual options for freelance marketplace wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

tried searching first but haven't found the exact answer I need. I am trying to run a freelance marketplace site on Wordpress that will be in both Chinese and English depending on the user's display language. Each freelancer profile, employer profile, project title and description, and project workspace communications will need to be translated into both languages.

The problem is that with using a plugin like WPML, each project will be split up into a separate post for each language. I am not sure exactly the extent that WPML is able to "sync" posts, and that is important because in this marketplace, an employer posts a project, in which a freelancer then views it and makes a bid. The project manager then accepts the best bid from a freelancer and they both enter a project workspace in which they can communicate in. If all posts are kept separate, and have separate URLs, wouldn't the functions for making a bid, accepting a bid, and the workspace be separate and therefore broken as well?

Anyone have this problem before? Is there a solution just for this sort of problem that is hiding out there?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate has a widget that you can embed in the header, or really anywhere on the page for that matter. Using some PHP to detect the browser/system language set, and JavaScript to set the "selected" translate option, you should be able to get the desired effect. One site I worked on made use of the widget without the JavaScript portion that selects it for you, and I can confirm that it works with WordPress on that manner at least. The JavaScript portion shouldn't be too hard, and I can edit my answer with actual code snippets/ideas if needed.

EDIT: A link to the site I mentioned, when I worked at a past employer, is still active here: http://adkalpha.com/gmlaw2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, Google Translate makes errors frequently when translating, and that will not work for what we are trying to create. We need to make sure that both sides completely understand each other

Comment: @borie88 I see, and yes, that makes sense. If you had another translation service in mind, you could do something similar with that service as well (there are many paid services available out there that will do similar things, and I was simply suggesting the Google option as it is free). If you want more complex solutions, that may require more advanced coding, there are options out there for sure, but you may be better off re-thinking your strategy if it gets much more complex.